# Keep track of trending Hashtags

Tags: php, mysql, hashtag

I'm adding "Hashtag Support" to my micro-blogging web app. Like twitter, google+, facebook and co. my app users may add hashtags to their messages. Hashtags are converted to html anchors pointing to the search page listing all related messages. Now **I want to also show "Trending Hashtags"**.

The messages are saved in a MySQL Table (InnoDB) along with the user_id and some meta_data.

I was thinking about the following way to handle the trending HT's:

1. ***Extract the hashtags from the message;***

   ```
   <?php
   preg_match_all( '/(#\w[\w\d]+)/', $message, $ht_matches );
   $hashtags     = array_unique($ht_matches[1]);
   $hashtags_str = implode( ' ', $hashtags );
   ```
2. ***save them in a separate row in the db record (space separated string);***

   ```
   e.g. #SanFrancisco #Boeing777 #AirplaneAccident

   --- 
   --- Table 'messages'
   ---
   +----+------------+--------------------------------------------+-----+
   | id | message    | hashtag                                    | ... |
   +----+------------+--------------------------------------------+-----+
   |  1 | ...        | #SanFrancisco #Boeing777 #AirplaneAccident | ... |
   +----+------------+--------------------------------------------+-----+
   ```
3. ***store each hashtag in a separate table if not exists along with meta-data;***

   ```
   --- 
   --- Table 'message_hashtags'
   ---
   +----+---------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
   | id | hashtag             | messages   | created_at          | updated_at          |
   +----+---------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
   |  1 | #SanFrancisco       |       1465 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
   +----+---------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
   |  2 | #Boeing777          |        294 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
   +----+---------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
   |  3 | #AirplaneAccident   |       1721 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
   +----+---------------------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+

   id           int         not null autoincrement
   hashtag      char(20)    not null 
   messages     int         not null default 0
   created_at   timestamp   not null 
   updated_at   timestamp   not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
   ```
4. ***query the db to fetch the trending hashtags, e.g.:***

   ```
   SELECT id FROM message_hashtags WHERE messages > 1 ORDER_BY messages LIMIT 10
   ```

This is all theoretical. Will this setup perform well in the long run? I'm concerned about possible bottlenecks and storage issues which might cause bad performance and awkwardness. I don't consider this as premature optimization, because if I don't do it the right way now, I'll need to change a lot later on if at all possible.

Hashtags are a popular subject, so I assume some of you have experience in dealing with HT's and the related search.

I'm open to suggestions and information that might point into another direction of working with hashtags.

Comment: I wanted to congrat you for the great question structuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be worthwhile to set up a many-to-many relationship between hashtags and messages. This includes adding 2 more tables:

- *hashtags* - With the fields `id` and `hashtag` (and maybe other meta-data), which will be a definition for all existing hashtags (and will update live when a new one is created by a user)
- *hashtags-messages* - With the fields `post_id` and `hashtag_id`, which will update when a user creates a post with hashtags. Every entry in this table is a single hashtag found on a post.

So for example:

```
hashtags
--------
id | hashtag
---+--------
1  | php
2  | madara
3  | awesome
```

```
hashtags-messages
-----------------
post_id    | hashtag_id
-----------+-----------
1          | 2
1          | 3
2          | 1
2          | 3
```

This implies that post 1 has the hashtags `#madara` and `#awesome`, while post 2 has `#php` and `#awesome`.

Querying for the most popular hashtags is as easy as querying for the count while grouping by hashtag_id. Using a JOIN, you can get all the information about the hashtag itself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BTW: With the example hashtags "php", "madara" and "awesome"... Is that intentional that it makes the reader think you're awesome in php? :P

Comment: @MarkusHofmann: No, it's to make them know that I am awesome, and also that PHP is awesome. The two aren't mutually exclusive though.